# How to correctly use GenerateDS for DDEX XML binding

Tags: xsd, xml-parsing, xml-binding, ddex, python-generateds

I am interested in Python XML binding for reading input files conforming to this schema:
http://ddex.net/xml/ern/341/release-notification.xsd

This XSD depends on a number of other ones though, most importantly:
http://ddex.net/xml/20120404/ddexC.xsd and
http://ddex.net/xml/20120404/ddex.xsd

My first attempt is by using [generateDS](http://cutter.rexx.com/~dkuhlman/generateDS.html). I am able to successfully generate binding for release-notification.xsd if I use --no-process-includes with:

```
./generateDS.py --no-process-includes -o release-notification.py release-notification.xsd
```

However, this leaves me with a Python object that is mostly useless since most of the ComplexTypes are defined in [ddexC.xsd](http://ddex.net/xml/20120404/ddexC.xsd).

If I try it without --no-process-includes, I get:

```
RuntimeError: Extension/restriction recursion detected.
Suggest you check definitions of types ArtistRole and ArtistRole.
```

The definition referred to is this one:

```
<xs:element name="ArtistRole" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="ddexC:ArtistRole">
....
<xs:complexType name="ArtistRole">
      <xs:simpleContent>
         <xs:extension base="ddex:ArtistRole">
....
```

So it seems like the ddex and ddexC namespaces get mixed up somehow and a circular reference is created.

Any advice here?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check out https://github.com/ddexnet which has a ddex lint script which you can use to generate full python objects which are validated against the full ERN schema located at http://ddex.net/xml/2010/ern-main/32.

(The linter makes use of the ddexC namespace under the hood too).

Answer (score 0):

I have created an object model for New Release message as part of a [DDEXUI](https://github.com/willm/DDEXUI) I am working on which may help you, The ddex module should give you something you can use. I plan to strip it in to a separate module at some point. For an example of how to use it, see the test directory.